# Why does the "Circle" class not see the parameters that I send to him?

Tags: javascript

Please tell me why, when I transfer coordinates `options` to class `Circle`, he does not see them?

I want to implement logic when the circle encounters any edge of the screen, it jumps back (change the value of the corresponding vector coordinate to the opposite value by the sign and call the `move()` method with the new vector)

**A little bit about the logic of my code:**
I implemented a Circle class with properties:

- x - the initial value of the x coordinate
- y - the initial value of the y coordinate
- diameter - values of width and height
- color - fill color

Method: `draw()` - draws on the screen an element that is described by the specified properties.

Method: `move({x = 0, y = 0})` - moves the drawn object along the vector (x, y) - every time period (100ms) changes (adds \ subtracts) the coordinates by the value of x and y in accordance

And the internal method `update()`, which changes the position of the drawn circle with the corresponding values of color, x, y of the object.

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
        this.x = options.x;
        this.y = options.y;
        this.diameter = options.diameter;
        this.color = options.color;
// the circle's move/update animation interval in ms
    }

    draw() {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        div.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
        div.style.width = `${this.diameter}px`;
        div.style.height = `${this.diameter}px`;
        div.style.border = "1px solid;";
        div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        // store the reference to the div element for later use
        this.circle = div;
        // use the refacterd positioning function
        this._reposition();
    }

    setColor(newColor) {
        return this.color = newColor;
    }

    move({x = 0, y = 0, duration = 1000}) {
        this.updateInterval = 100;
        this.direction = 1;
        this.destX = 0,
            this.destY = 4;
        // store the current time in ms
        this.startTime = Date.now();
        this.duration = duration;
        // if a previous setInterval of this circle instance
        // is still running, clear it (stop it)

        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        // start the update
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this._update.bind(this));
    }

    _update() {
        // set the x and y coordinates according to the progress
        let newX = this.x + this.direction * this.destX;
        let newY = this.y + this.direction * this.destY;
        if (newY >= window.innerHeight - this.diameter) {
            this.direction = -1;
        } else if (newY <= 0) {
            this.direction = 1;
        }
        if (newX >= window.innerWidth - this.diameter) {
            this.direction = -1;
        } else if (newX <= 0) {
            this.direction = 1;
        }
        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;

        this._reposition();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this._update.bind(this));
    }

    _reposition() {
        // set the position of the circle instance
        this.circle.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        this.circle.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
    }
}
const options = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    diameter: 100,
    color: 'red'
};
const circle = new Circle(options);
circle.draw();
circle.setColor("green");
circle.move({x: 1235, y:0});
```

Comment: What's the problem? The circle bounces up and down. What goes wrong?

Comment: It does not work by: const options = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    diameter: 100,
    color: 'red'
};
And the color did not change by method: circle.setColor("green");

Comment: well colors get set in draw... you call once so how would it run that code again?

Comment: And what is `intervalId`?

Comment: You need two different `direction` properties, one for `X` and another for `Y`.

Comment: Maybe `_reposition` should just call `this.draw()` so all the styles are updated.

Comment: This results in the reset of all changes that are initialized by the methods and causes the error: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 1):

Your _update method never resets the color, try

```
 this.circle.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
```

inside your _update call :)

Comment: thx, maybe you can tell me how to make the class "Circle" move according to given coordinates in "options" ?

Comment: In the method move({x, y, duration}) you never use the argument object's x and y properties (for instance, assigning them to this.x, this.y). Also I'd recommend using a pre-built vector library if you're going to be making anything more complex, it gets confusing real quickly to try to do vector math "by hand" in every moving object.